# Implementing scrolling categories div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement the design attached. As you can see there is a list of horizontal categories and someone can scroll to the left and right to see all the categories. Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tryed overflow-x: scroll

Comment: Add minimum reproducible example, so that we can figure out where you are doing wrong

Comment: @PotaOnasys You tried `overflow-x: scroll` and how it went out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use white-space method. Please try code below

```
<div class="scrolling">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

.scrolling {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```